# Pack two adjacent views in a spread-chain ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a set of half a dozen widgets chained together in a spread chain in a ConstraintLayout.  There are no other layouts in this view, only the ConstraintLayout and the widgets.

Two of the widgets in the center should be closer together, because one is the title for the other:

```
widget-title
widget-EditText
```

I want to use a spread chain (Center Vertically) on all of the widgets in my view, but I want these two in particular to be packed vertically together, while honoring the bottom margin in the top one and the top margin in the bottom one.

I can't figure out how to do it.  I tried putting them together as children of a vertical LinearLayout, but it refuses to participate properly in the spread chain -- it goes to the top and many of the other widgets disappear.

I've tried adding additional constraints to the two views, but the spread chain seems to override all the additional constraints and they have no effect.  The only exception is aligning their baselines, which DOES work but smushes them together, which I don't want.

I don't see a way to create multiple spread chains within the same ConstraintLayout, in such a way that they all spread evenly.

How do you group two (or more) widgets within a chain so that their spread rules are different from the rest of the chain?  Or failing that, how do you construct multiple chains that all spread the same?

Comment: A picture would help here. Have you looked at using a guideline in the `ConstraintLayout`? That might give you some additional flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have gone wrong when you mapped the two center widgets in a `LinearLayout`. The following layout does just that and seems to work the way I think you want it to. I didn't add a lot of `View`s in the chain, but it is enough to get the idea. Check it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TextView2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer convinced me to go back and try again.  I was able to reproduce the original behavior in Android Studio with a fresh layout -- the LinearLayout was behaving poorly again.  However, this time I tried settings its layout_height to wrap_content, and that fixed everything.  So thank you.